# ¿Enviar JSON método POST javascript firebase function?

Tags: firebase, post

estoy intentando enviar un POST a una función en firebase. Desde postman funciona, pero desde javascript(jquery) solo logro enviarlo como texto plano y se almacena de forma incorrecta en la base de datos de firebase. Intenté convirtiendo usando JSON.stringify pero no funciona, ni siquiera retorna un error. Código ejemplo en el que me estoy basando

```
     var arr = { City: 'Moscow', Age: 25 }; $.ajax(   {
       url: "https://url",
       method: "POST",
       data: JSON.stringify(arr),
       contentType: "application/json"   });
```

y al pasarlo como texto plano, en la base de datos queda así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vuelvo a indicar que desde POSTMAN se inserta correctamente enviandolo como JSON
Agradezco cualquier solución así sea usando el objeto request.

Comment: No da error, pero no registra en firebase

Comment: En primer lugar me tienes que disculpar porque me he equivocado con lo de `JSON.stringify()` he probado el código y funciona... siempre y cuando tenga la url de esta manera: `https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/.json` (ojo con el `/.json` al final)... en el segundo lugar elimina la respuesta tuya ya que no es una respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo corregí de la siguiente forma:

```
var data = { City: 'Moscow', Age: 25 };
        $.ajax({
                url : 'https://tu_url',
                data : data, 
                method : 'POST', //en este caso
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(response){
                       console.log("Success");
                },
                error: function(error){
                       console.log(error);
                }
        });
```

Comment: Podrias explicar cual fue el problema y como lo solucionaste?

Comment: No sé si fui poco claro al preguntar, pero el problema radicaba en hacer un POST desde javaScritpt a una api creada usando firebase functions, Usando postman el objeto(JSON) creado se guardaba correctamente en la base de datos, pero, cuando lo insertaba desde javaScript (JQUERY o usando REQUEST) el objeto se guardaba como un string, quedando de la forma que aparece en la captura de pantalla, lo cuál no me convenía porque al hacer GET devuelve un JSON. La solución fue usar dataType:'json' en la petición ajax

Comment: Por favor explica todo eso en la respuesta. Si no, es como que le falta contexto.